# Shapely install on Mac with pyenv-virtualenv failed

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, shapely

OS: mac, El Capitan
Python version: 2.7.11

I tried to install shapely after setting up a brand new pyenv-virtualenv and changing my directory to use that 'pyenv version' and I get the following error:

```
dhcp-uris-1290:seam Chelsea$ pip install shapely
Collecting shapely
Using cached Shapely-1.5.15.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/1l/r_vh6y997rdgk6sdnkqsntpr0000gn/T/pip-build-odrxBR/shapely/setup.py", line 38, in <module>
    from shapely._buildcfg import geos_version_string, geos_version, \
  File "/private/var/folders/1l/r_vh6y997rdgk6sdnkqsntpr0000gn/T/pip-build-odrxBR/shapely/shapely/_buildcfg.py", line 88, in <module>
    clibs = get_geos_config('--clibs')
  File "/private/var/folders/1l/r_vh6y997rdgk6sdnkqsntpr0000gn/T/pip-build-odrxBR/shapely/shapely/_buildcfg.py", line 71, in get_geos_config
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
  File "/Users/Chelsea/.pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/Users/Chelsea/.pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1334, in _execute_child
    child_exception = pickle.loads(data)
  File "/Users/Chelsea/.pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1388, in loads
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/Users/Chelsea/.pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 864, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/Users/Chelsea/.pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 972, in load_string
    raise ValueError, "insecure string pickle"
ValueError: insecure string pickle
-----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/1l/r_vh6y997rdgk6sdnkqsntpr0000gn/T/pip-build-odrxBR/shapely/
```

The whole reason I got into this virtualenv business is because I was getting insecure string pickle errors when trying to use matplotlib with system python on el capitan, which is known to be an issue (https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5314) , so I tried to build my own new framework and run it, that didn't work, and now tried to set up a virtualenv but it looks like virtualenv might just not play nicely with certain python packages? :'( 
Shapely install correctly OUTSIDE of a virtualenv on my machine, with system python. Sadly system python, as mentioned, was not playing nicely with matplotlib.

P.S. these are the packages I have installed in this particular pyenv-virtualenv:

```
cycler (0.10.0)  
distribute (0.7.3)  
matplotlib (1.5.1)  
numpy (1.11.0)  
pip (8.1.2)  
pyparsing (2.1.4)  
python-dateutil (2.5.3)  
pytz (2016.4)  
setuptools (21.1.0)  
six (1.10.0)  
wheel (0.29.0)
```